# Chrome Extension: Get current webpage url from background.html not stable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Try to get url in background.html through background.js in Chrome extension.

```
var myURL = "about:blank"; // A default url just in case below code doesn't work
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) { // onUpdated should fire when the selected tab is changed or a link is clicked 
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        myURL = tab.url;
    });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
  logUrl();
})

function logUrl() {
          ...
          eventProperties.setProperty('URI', myURL);
          ...
}
```

`myURL` sometimes shows as "about:blank", it shows actual url after reloading the page.
How shall I fix this?

Comment: This event is asynchronous so your code is inherently broken. Use `myURL = changeInfo.url || tab.url` instead of getSelected and call logUrl right inside onUpdated not outside.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks. I actually need to call logUrl() inside contextMenus listener.